# Find common keys in two sorted arrays that prints them in o(sqrt n)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search-tree

How do I write pseudocode for the following problem?

Given two sorted arrays X and Y with lg n and n keys respectively. I need a space and time efficient algorithm that finds the keys common to X and Y and prints them. It should run in o(sqrt n), i.e. (small 'o')time.

My attempt: Do you think binary search would be an option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I make of it. There are two sorted arrays with log(n) and n elements. You need to find the elements common to both.

You can iterate through X and binary search for each element of X in Y. If the search is successful, print the element. That would be in f(x) = c * (log(n))^2 time, where c is some constant.

As for every k > 0, you can find a constant a such that f(x) < k * sqrt(n) holds for all x > a, hence this solution is o(sqrt(n)).

EDIT: Here is the pseudocode (pretty simple):

```
input X
input Y
n = number of elements in Y
for i = 0 to n:
    if(binary_search(X[i] in Y) = found)print X[i]
```

Comment: thank you very much for explaining. May i know if it is possible you can show me psuedocode as well ?

Comment: I have added the pseudocode. Its pretty simple. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For Shikhar Gupta's solution,I have one improvement. Shikhar's solution doesn't make use of  the fact that X is sorted too.So through every iteration,we can reduce the lower or higher boundary of Y.This can reduce the run time as well.

In order to prove O((log(n))^2) < O(sqrt(n)),we only need to prove the derivative of the first is smaller than the second.Which means 2log(n)/n < 1/sqrt(n).Then we have to prove log(n) < sqrt(n).This is pretty tricky.